# angularjs http not working in mvc when using get list of data

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I want simply fetch the list of items using angular js .I am using angular code and using $http. but its not working. I hit on action method and try to return json. but when i am trying it. it return full json on view.

```html
@section scripts{
  
    <script src="~/Scripts/ang.js"></script>
}

<div ng-app="StudentApp" class="container">
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Search Student" ng-model="searchStudent" />
    <br />
    <div ng-controller="StudentController">
        <table class="table" ng-init="initData()">
            <tr ng-repeat="r in data | filter : searchStudent" >
                <td>{{ r.Col_Title }}</td>
                <td>{{ r.Col_Descrp }}</td>
                
            </tr>
        <table>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
 public ActionResult GetCollections()
    {
        var lst = eShoppingEntitiesContetxt.Collections.Where(s => s.IsActive == true).ToList();
        var result = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(lst, new JsonSerializerSettings
                 {
                     ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore
                 });
        return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
      //  return View();
    }
```

```
 var myApp = angular.module('StudentApp', []);
    myApp.controller('StudentController', function ($scope, $http) {

    $http.get('/User/GetCollections') // added an '/' along with deleting Controller portion
        .then(function (response) {

            $scope.data = response.data
        })})
```

```
<div ng-app="StudentApp" class="container">
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Search Student" ng-model="searchStudent" />
    <br />
    <div ng-controller="StudentController">
        <table class="table">
            <tr ng-repeat="r in data | filter : searchStudent" >
                <td>{{ r.name }}</td>
                <td>{{ r.country }}</td>

            </tr>
        <table>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image: This is result on front view]

Comment: Could you show the JSON which is returned?

Comment: Show us your Controller, the Controller should return `JsonResult` instead of `ActionResult`.

Comment: See my controller Method

Comment: Add that into your original question... not in comment.

Comment: Ok Rosdi kasim i put it in question

Comment: Any one help me?

Comment: I get list of items in json form. but its not work

Comment: please post your json.

Comment: what do you mean anoop?

Comment: could you add your json structure in question ?

Comment: Your Controller is ok, but you are not showing your full angular code, I believe you are not loading the data at all. You are not supposed to call $http.get inside angular controller like that.

Comment: I use only this snippet of code in angular shown above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
var myApp = angular.module('StudentApp', []);
myApp.controller('StudentController', function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.initData = function() {
        $http.get('/User/GetCollections') // added an '/' along with deleting Controller portion
            .then(function(response) {
                $scope.data = response.data;
            });
    }
});
```

In your view (notice the `ng-init="initData()"` in the table)

```
<div ng-app="StudentApp" class="container">
<br/>
<br/>
<input type="text" placeholder="Search Student" ng-model="searchStudent" />
<br />
<div ng-controller="StudentController">
    <table class="table" ng-init="initData()">
        <tr ng-repeat="r in data | filter : searchStudent" >
            <td>{{ r.name }}</td>
            <td>{{ r.country }}</td>

        </tr>
    <table>
</div>
```

Comment: When my hit goes to controller method it return only show data in json form on browser. i think there is problem with controller method check my above question. i put a image of my output content

Comment: I know why, but you need to show your complete view code. Right now you show only snippet of angular and a snippet of cshtml, the problem is in that file. Paste your entire cshtml file.

Comment: I follow below link? can you explain what thing i miss in below link code https://www.infragistics.com/community/blogs/dhananjay_kumar/archive/2015/05/13/how-to-use-angularjs-in-asp-net-mvc-and-entity-framework-4.aspx

Answer (score 0):

As your question says : `it return full json on view...`.

So I hope you forgot to convert your stringfy json to object. Like :

`$scope.data = angular.fromJson(response.data);`

**Update**

Your not calling REST api method, rather MVC controller, which will ofcourse render view with json.

you need to create a REST API method. like :

```
[Route("User/GetCollections")]
public JsonResult GetCollections()
{
    // compute your data.

    return new Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

and remove `ng-init="initData()"` from html. Since your controller will bind $scope.data.

Comment: I try it but in my action method it returns only json content on view.

Comment: `'/User/GetCollections'`, this is not a REST api method, rather MVC controller. You need to create `REST` controller. I will edit my answer

Comment: I follow this link Please tell me explain me what changes i need now https://www.infragistics.com/community/blogs/dhananjay_kumar/archive/2015/05/13/how-to-use-angularjs-in-asp-net-mvc-and-entity-framework-4.aspx

Comment: @DeftsoftDotnet: did you used `JsonResult` instead of `ActionResult` in `public ActionResult GetCollections()` ?

Comment: Yes i also use JsonResult instead of Actionresult but same problem. when i put static data in $scope.data and return view instead of return json it works. but i want data from database

Comment: really can't figure out any issue by your link provided, just try last thing. take out your `http.get()` call to some factory or service and call the service\factory method from your controller. (like it done in the link you mentioned), and use `.then()` not `.sucess`